# Why canvas undo not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm working on a drawing page where I have multiple buttons. My problem is with the undo button. When I draw 3 lines on the canvas, and then click on undo, everything works great. But when I'm trying to draw again, the undooed lines are appearing again.

Can anyone please help me with this?

This is my undo function:

```js
function cUndo() {
  if (cStep > 0) {
    cStep--;
    var canvasPic = new Image();
    canvasPic.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    canvasPic.src = cPushArray[cStep];
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 575, 575);
    canvasPic.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(canvasPic, 0, 0, 575, 575);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the entire app:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLu4f20r/7/)

I know it's a lot of code to take in, but I've been messing around my head with this for a while, and I can't figure out what am I doing wrong, or what I haven't done. Thank you.

Comment: When undo/redo'ing. remember to have a way to set the initial state. TL;DR though it does not appear from a quick glance an initial state is ever recorded or that it can be set when undo reaches 0.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying. Can you help me please with a solution?

Comment: You need to store the first state somehow, either by storing the "blank" image or have a way to reset it to the initial image when last undo is hit.